# Google Licensing Service - Understanding the concept

Tags: android, android-lvl

I don't understand the concept of Google's Licensing Service

Scenario:
user A purchases an app on device X.
User A then accesses the Android market via his other device Y to install the app and he doesn't have to pay a second time since he uses the same account on both devices.

The app makes a license check request which includes either device specific data or random data generated during the installation and stored on the device.

As far as I understand that extra data would be different on device X and Y therefore the license check request is different for the same user and app but still recognized as valid.

So that extra request data is also stored on the licensing server per user/ app/ device during the download from the Android market?

User A cannot copy the app from device X to device Y, the license check would fail since that device or installation specific data is only stored on the server when installing the app from the Android market?

Comment: what 'extra data' are you referring to?

Comment: I am referring to the data passed on to the constructor of ServerManagedPolicy as described here: http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/licensing.html

Answer (score 0):

Certain information is saved locally. For example: `ServerManagedPolicy` saves the last response, validity timestamp, retry until, max retries and retry count as local-device data.

Especially because of the Last Response being stored locally, you are encouraged to obfuscate the local data (otherwise a malaicious user could enter their own local data, indicating the license as valid) and the `AESObfuscator` class is provided as:

> An Obfuscator that uses AES to encrypt data.

When you construct the `AESObfuscator`, you provide a `byte[] salt, String applicationId, String deviceId`. The [`PBEKeySpec`](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/crypto/spec/PBEKeySpec.html#PBEKeySpec%28char%5B%5D,%20byte%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29)'s password is based upon the `applicationId` and `deviceId` (you can see in the source code provided).

The comment in `com.example.android.market.licensing.MainActivity` indicates you can provide more than just `Secure.ANDROID_ID` as the `deviceId`. How secure you need to make this is up to your discretion - it could be as simple as hardcoding a value in your application `(new String(byte[]{(byte) 75, (byte) 12}) + Secure.ANDROID_ID)` or some other cryptography scheme (whose discussion may be more appropriate for a cryptography forum).

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking your time to write an answer. Does that mean that device or installation specific data is not sent to the server only used to store the response data?

Comment: answer updated to describe the use of `DEVICE_ID` in the sample code, please check the checkmark outline if this answers your questions.

Comment: Again, thanks a lot. A final note on the issue: I've got a device - Motorola Milestone, Android 2.2.1 - which is not providing a device identifier (using the IMEI is not an option for me), so I have to use random data with no connection to the hardware, so the installation files could be copied to any other device, you only have to share an account from which the app was once legally purchased. I am pretty sure that the admins of those warez sites know exactly how to do that.

Comment: Google recommends not to use a device limiter which would also additionally require a backend server.

Comment: A `DeviceLimiter` is different from what I am describing of using `ANDROID_ID` for your `AESObfuscator`'s password.

Comment: Thanks, I am aware of that, but ANDROID_ID is not available with all devices, I know it first hand from my phone but there's also a post on that http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/identifying-app-installations.html. My point is a soon as you can't use unique device data to encrypt and store the server response, that data could be copied over to any device you only have to forge the account info? Ok, thanks, I appreciate your contribution. I'll like to finish that discussion now and go back studying the available licensing infos again hoping to finally grasp it.

Comment: There are other ways to generate a password, the device id is just used in the sample code. Please remember to say Thank You by marking as correct answer if it has answered you question :)